# PHP Upload File - right code but can't find the file/path

Tags: php, file, upload

First question for quite a while. Essentially, I've got some code that (1) works perfectly in the live environment, (2) used to work in my home OSX environment but (3) doesn't work now.

The HTML:

```
<form id="upload_form" action="php/upload_class_list.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" >
    <label>File:</label>
    <input name="myfile" type="file" size="35" />
    <input id="upload_submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</form>
```

The PHP file:

```
$destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$result = 0;

$target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['myfile']['name']);

if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {   
   ...
}

sleep(1);
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">top.upload_class_list(<?php echo $result; ?>);</script>
```

The script fires at the end, but the PHP code doesn't enter the `if` (in the local development environment) and so `$result` remains at 0.

It seems it's not picking up the `path` of the file to be uploaded; `$destination_path` points to the folder where the PHP file is located, and not where the file is found.

I think my local environment may have stopped working when I changed to Mountain Lion and rebuilt the PHP setup.

What is missing to stop the file being found?

Let me emphasise: exactly the same code works fine in my live Hostmonster setup, so it's an environment problem, I guess :)

Thanks.

Comment: echo `$destination_path` and `$target_path` and see what gets outputted.

Comment: @chriz Both point to the folder in which the PHP script lives. The `basename...` adds nothing more to `$target_path` than was in `$destination_path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
> ...
> }
>
> What is missing to stop the file being found?

What makes you think the problem is the file being *found*? Maybe the file *is* found, but what fails is the `move`... for example because the Web server has no permissions to write into the `target_path`.

You can check:

```
$src = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$dst = $target_path;

if (!file_exists($src))
   die("Okay, the file is actually not found");

if (!is_readable($src))
   die("Very bad hosting juju. The file was uploaded but I can't read it?!?");

if (!is_writeable($destination_path))
   die("As expected, you can't upload a file here. This is a good thing.");

@touch($dst);
if (!file_exists($dst))
   die("So call me a Marine, the file SHOULD be writeable (which is not so good), and yet I could not write it! Perhaps disk full? User overquota? Some weird security setup?");
```

The reason why it's a good thing is because that directory holds *executable PHP files*, and if anyone could upload a PHP file in there, well, that would be a major security hole.

You can set aside another directory and make it writeable (**remember to put in there a .htaccess or other system to prohibit read/execute access from the outside**).

Comment: As you say, the issue is with the writing. Values return for `$_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name']` and `$target_path`, and your `!is_writeable` falls over. Nice job. Thanks :)

Comment: I hardcoded the `$target_path` to a better directory and it's working :)

Comment: Remember to protect the directory via .htaccess ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this; not quite sure how to do that at the mo', but I'll find out :)

Answer (score -1):

may be this

```
<?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
    echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Why 'uploaded' and 'uploadedfile'? The `file` field in the uploaded form is named `myfile`.

Comment: i know but this is script from my project and it is working very well.

Comment: I am sure it does. Even so, you may want to check your array indexes: you first seem to call your field `uploaded`, and then `uploadedfile`. Which is it?